# Which part of code (function) handles received transactions?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I was trying to understand the flow of control between functions (operations performed and their order) when a transaction is received.

Comment: When *any* transaction is recieved, or just when you recieve a transaction that pays to you?

Comment: In both case, which functions will be called ? and in what order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Any transaction

[main.cpp, AcceptToMemoryPool](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/b88cb1a96eb670ca1f36cdc3fa908a23bffa18c5/src/main.cpp#L879):

```
bool AcceptToMemoryPool(CTxMemPool& pool, CValidationState &state, const CTransaction &tx, bool fLimitFree,
                        bool* pfMissingInputs, bool fRejectInsaneFee)
```

#### A transaction that pays to or from you

[wallet.cpp, CWallet::AddToWallet](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/d7e195048342afae9168377cebfc22ab000728a5/src/wallet.cpp#L550):

```
bool CWallet::AddToWallet(const CWalletTx& wtxIn, bool fFromLoadWallet)
```

Comment: can you please explain the arguments passed ?

Comment: @somesh Could you explain why you want to know? I initially assumed that you wanted to instrument the code somehow.